# Any REST endpoint which prioritize/update the bamboo build queue?

Tags: bamboo

Any REST endpoint which prioritize/update the bamboo build queue?

http://host:8085/rest/api/latest/queue?expand=queuedBuilds

want to automate this process using python for release builds to reduce the waiting time.
Checked above endpoint , but it only add/delete builds from queue. want to move up the bamboo builds which has high priority.

Answer (score 2):

Per the latest Bamboo REST API [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.10.3/#d2e1906) (6.10.3) there is not a way to do this without creating something custom or using a third party plugin.

Comment: do you have any third party plugin which provides endpoint for this functionality?

Comment: @AnRedd: Atlassian Labs has an unsupported one here: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1216287/queue-priority-plugin-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview

Comment: what exactly does Atlassian mean by an unsupported plugin?